# The message encryption program crashes

Tags: c++, string, encryption

When I try to compile it, no errors. Then I run the compiled file and it just crashes with no errors.

> Program has stopped working: Close or Debug

The goal of my program is to encrypt and then decrypt message.

Here is a code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

char Encrypt(char Char) { return Char * Char / 2; }
char Decrypt(char Char) { return Char * 2 / Char; }
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  string text = "Hello World, guys!";
  string encryptedtext;
  string decryptedtext;
  for (int i = 0; i <= text.size(); i++) {
    encryptedtext += Encrypt(text[i]);
  }
  cout << encryptedtext;
  for (int i = 0; i <= encryptedtext.size(); i++) {
    decryptedtext += Decrypt(encryptedtext[i]);
  }
  cout << decryptedtext;
}
```

I saw "Process exited after 0.6444 seconds with return value 3221225620"
Guys, I made how you said, but error is the same. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

char Encrypt(char Char) {

return Char * Char / 2;

}

char Decrypt(char Char) {

    return Char * 2 / Char;

}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
string text = "Hello World, guys!";
string encryptedtext;
string decryptedtext;
for (char ch : text) {
encryptedtext += Encrypt(ch);
}
cout << encryptedtext;
for (char ch : encryptedtext) {
decryptedtext += Decrypt(ch);
}
cout << decryptedtext;
}
```

Comment: maybe chose "debug" and it will tell you what is the problem

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: "When I try to compile it, no erros." - That *in no way* guarantees that it is *correct*.

Comment: _`i <= text.size()`_ is wrong, change to `i < text.size()`. The other loop condition analogous.

Comment: It says "Choose JIT-Debugger and in available debuggers is Visual Studio Community 2017. This doesn't help.

Comment: Break out your debugger. Step through your program line by line. Observe the variable values and control flow. Note where they/it deviates from your expectations. Think about why that happened...

Comment: @SarnaifChannel A debugger doesn't show you bugs in any direct way, it allows you to inspect the program's variables as you control its execution. When the program crashes, you could use the debugger to see, for example, that `i` was out of range. You would then start investigating how `i` got out of range by running the program again, this time controlling the execution by stepping or with breakpoints, and keeping an eye on `i`.

Comment: Off-topic:  Your variable and class names should differ by more than case.  For example, `Char` and `char`.  Many compilers will recognize differences in the first 32 characters.  That's a lot of possibilities to have different names.  I often use a Thesaurus when I can't come up with different names.

Comment: Your expression `Char * Char` may overflow.  Better to convert them to larger data type, such as `signed int` or `unsigned int` before the multiplication.  In general, multiplications may overflow, so convert them to a larger capacity data type before multiplying.

Answer (score 2):

Your for loops are wrong

```
for (int i = 0; i <= text.size(); i++) {
    encryptedtext += Encrypt(text[i]);
}
```

should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < text.size(); i++) {   // use < not <=
    encryptedtext += Encrypt(text[i]);
}
```

and the same error for the second loop.

But better would be a *range based for loop*

```
for (char ch : text) {
    encryptedtext += Encrypt(ch);
}
```

which is easier to understand and avoids this kind of error.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert `3221225620` to hex you'll get `0xC0000094` which is the windows error code for "divide by zero".

This is caused by the for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= text.size(); i++)
```

The last value of `i` that you pass to `text[i]` is `text.size()` but the last element in `text` is `text[text.size()-1]`. This is undefined behaviour but the implementation of `std::string` presumably null terminates the string buffer so `text[text.size()]` returns `\0`. This causes `\0` to be passed to `Decrypt` which gives the `divide by zero` error. The corrected for loop is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < text.size(); i++)
```

Note that your algorithm doesn't work as `Decrypt` isn't the reverse of `Encrypt` and the values returned from `Encrypt` overflow the range storable in `char`. This also produces additional divide by zero errors, for example the value of the space character is `32`. `32 * 32 / 2` is `512` which when truncated to a `char` gives `0`.

Comment: I think this is because of a divide by a space or something. But I don't know how to solve dat.

Comment: @SarnaifChannel yes, your algorithm produces a null character from a space input, I've edited my answer